# using UMFPACK with QTCreator

Tags: c++, qt, cygwin, umfpack

I have been trying to setup the UMFPACK to run on QT creator for a while now but with no results.

I first tried to build the UMFPACK using the cygwin for windows but some friend proposed using the built in package in the cygwin.

I used the library built in but when I point the QT creator to the library an error pops up indicating that the library couldn't be opened. I figured out that the QT creator is using the MSVC to build the project but the UMFPACK is compiled with mingw in cygwin. i tried to define a custom compiler pointing to the cygwin  directory but i get the following error "Compilers produce code for different ABIs".

QT creator error

[image]

How can I setup QT to use the cygwin so that I can use the builtin UMFPACK package. Or does anyone has a reference to UMFPACK built for MSVC.

Comment: SuiteSparse contains UMFPACK and you can install it using [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/suitesparse).

Comment: @HenriMenke I installed the vcpkg and installed suitesparse package. when I include it in the QT creator a link1140 error is displayed. In a previous post a friend told me that this error is caused by compatibility error between the compiler used to build the library and that used in qt creator. I'm using MSVC 2015 in the qt creator, do you have any idea what is causing this error ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045648/qt-creator-linking-external-library-vcpkg-error-link1104